# Ionic android build issue in linux

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have successfully installed `cordova v6.3.1, ionic v2.0.0` and `Android Studio`

**OS:** Virtualbox (Xubuntu)

when i run ionic build android

I get below error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.749 secs

Error: /var/lib/mymachine/ionic-01/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
```

Few post suggested to install Android support repository and Google Repository. I installed it. But still i face the face problem.

[image]

Comment: are you getting this error after adding any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. In my case it was simple java webapp which was using gradle. This project used java 6. My java 6 was not installed properly. Thats why I had the below issue.

[image]

gradle was not able to find the **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts**

This is a symlink to another file which was not present.

So I removed my jdk and re-installed it. That solved the problem.